# Is it possible to make a plane out of meta objects?

Tags: meta-objects

Yes, I know, *Add > Metaball > Plane*.

But how can I make a large plane?

Scaling it affects all meta objects in the scene.
I thought of connecting a bunch of meta planes together, however this isn't a perfect solution as it's a little bumpy (and if you need a really big plane it won't help your framerate)

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plane meta-elements have an X and Y Size you can edit in the *Properties editor > Object Data > Active Element*:

[image]

it looks like this is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Where in the properties editor?

Comment: @MikePan Sorry, I meant where **in** the properties editor? I looked in the meta object panel, but there is nothing of the sort there.

Comment: Sorry I misread. You need to have the metaplane selected in edit mode.